# wpf databinding to downloaded data

Tags: wpf, json, data-binding

I am having a bit of trouble understanding the correct way to do the following:

The data I am binding to exists on the internet as a json file. On a timer tick, I download it and using a JavaScriptSerializer, I deserialize it into a class.

Now, I want to bind to that data but when I deserialize, it creates a new class, so my binding breaks (meaning I have to set the ItemsSource or DataContext again).

Does anyone know a way around this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the control that you are trying to bind your data to? If you can bind an observable collection as your data source, all you need to do is to clear your observable collection before fetching the data, and just add the fetched record to the collection post deserialization.
If you do not use ObservableCollection, you can add public properties to your ViewModel and  just refresh those when you get the data back. This will ensure the refresh happens becuase your view is bound to public properties of your view model and not aware of the object returned from the call.

Answer (score 0):

After binding deserialized data you should call `PropertyChange` event of the property you want rebind. In case the selected value is in the new (deserialized) collection it should be reselected.